# Gradient disappears after float applied to logo and text in the header

Tags: html, css, header

I floated my logo and H1 text in the header to the left. And I made sure to clear those floats in my nave bar, but something strange happened, the gradient that was supposed to be applied to the header disappeared. Does anybody know why?

This is a snippet of my html:

```
<body>
<div class="contentwrapper">
<!-- beginning of header element -->
<div class="gradientheaderfooter">
 <header class="banner" role="banner">
   <img src="images/GoodKarmaBikes_LogoRGB_Web.jpg" alt="Good Karma Bikes GKB Logo">  
   <h1>Good Karma Bikes</h1>
 </header>
</div>
</body>
```

And this is a snippet of my css:

```
body {
background-image: url(../images/GKBBackground_Gradient1.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.contentwrapper {
max-width: 1366px;
margin: 0 auto;
outline: 1px solid #333333;
}

.gradientheaderfooter {
background-image:
linear-gradient(
  to bottom,
  silver, green 90%
);
}

.banner {

}

.banner img{
float: left;
}
.banner h1{
float: left;
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
}
```

I put these codes into jsfiddle, but the logo would not show up. Here is the link to the jsfiddle though:

http://jsfiddle.net/shihfa/haqkbgq4/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to isolate this more. Show us just the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: I can remove the CSS coding for the Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean look arrogant by asking a question, then answering it myself. But I got the answer from my professor, and I figured that somebody out there could use the solution to this problem.

Change the code to this:

```
/* === Eliminate the div class below === */
.gradientheader {
}
/* === Eliminate the div class above === */

.banner {
 background-image:
linear-gradient(
to bottom,
silver, green 90%
);
overflow: hidden;
}
/* === Add "overflow: hidden;" above. When you float elements inside of another element, the     
parent element collapses and does not acknowledge the existence of the child floated elements. 
"overflow: hidden" on the parent element is one way to contain the floats. === */

.banner img{
float: left;
margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}

.banner h1{
float: left;
font-size: 6em;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.banner {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

add this in your css.